# PHP & Oracle - Binding a boolean to an oracle function call via php fails

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, boolean, oracle-call-interface

I have an oracle function, that i am trying to access via php:

```
FUNCTION internInsertData( RefId  IN NUMBER, nProjektId  IN NUMBER, nKeepMaster IN NUMBER, Position IN NUMBER,CheckPosition IN BOOLEAN, TeilanlageId IN NUMBER,  TAElementId IN NUMBER)
```

This function needs a boolean parameter "CheckPosition", which seems to cause an error when binding a value using a variable to it.

When i run

```
$result="";
$sql ="BEGIN :result := PRO_1.PKG_REGELELEMENT.internInsertData(28236,653,1,1,true,123,42741); END;";

$stmt = oci_parse($this->oracle->getConnection(), $sql);

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":result", $result,12345);
oci_execute($stmt);
```

everything works fine.

I want to pass the values by binding.

But when i bind a boolean variable to the call, it fails to execute:

```
    $booli = true;
    $result="";

    $sql ="BEGIN :result := PRO_1.PKG_REGELELEMENT.internInsertData(28236,653,1,1,:booli,123,42741); END;";
    $stmt = oci_parse($this->oracle->getConnection(), $sql);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":result", $result,12345);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":booli", $booli,12345);
    oci_execute($stmt);
```

This causes a warning & the PL/SQL script stops:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'INTERNINSERTDATA'

It seems that i am not binding the boolean the right way. Binding to the other numeric parameters works. Only the boolean doesn't. What am i missing ?

Comment: Try adding the last parameter to oci_bind_by_name.  You need to use the constant SQLT_BOL for booleans.  By default, it is converting everything to SQLT_CHR.  Also, note that this only works for Oracle 12c.

Comment: i new about the SQLT types, but i couldn't find anything representing boolean in the PHP docs...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php

Comment: ok, i overlooked that.sadly i am using oracle 11, so i think i would have to pass it inline...

Comment: Just convert to a number, 0=false, 1=true.

Comment: Are you refering to changing the parameter type from boolean to number ? i implemented a workaround for booleans by using "true" or "false" within the call, like in the first, working example... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to bind boolean data using less than Oracle 12c, like swstephe said in his comment.

You will have to pass the value inline, like this:

*$sql ="BEGIN :result := PRO_1.PKG_REGELELEMENT.internInsertData(28236,653,1,1,
**true**,123,42741); END;";*

Or use SQLT_BOL if you are able to use Oracle 12c or greater.